# What does "scale" in laplace.ppf refer to?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I refer to documentation [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.laplace.html).

What does the "scale" parameter refer to? Does it refer to "b" as described in the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) entry?

Comment: The documentation that you linked to already explains what `scale` is.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation that you linked to says:

> The probability density function for laplace is:
>
> `laplace.pdf(x) = 1/2 * exp(-abs(x))`
>
> The probability density above is defined in the “standardized” form. To shift and/or scale the distribution use the loc and scale parameters. Specifically, `laplace.pdf(x, loc, scale)` is identically equivalent to `laplace.pdf(y) / scale` with `y = (x - loc) / scale`.

In other words, `laplace.pdf(x, loc, scale) = 1/(2*scale) * exp(-abs(x-loc)/scale)`.  Comparing that to the Wikipedia entry confirms that `scale` is equivalent to `b` in the formula given there.

To determine what the scale/loc parameters mean for scipy functions, you need to read the descriptions in the documentation that relate them to the mathematical characterization of the function.